# Can't drag'n'drop files in Microsoft Android emulator

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

So, as the title states, I can't drag'n'drop files in Microsoft Android emulator. I think the problem isn't in ADB, because it sees it(at least I can target device in Visual Studio). Any ideas?

Comment: What is the behavior you are seeing when you attempt to drag and drop?  What have you tried?  Have you checked out this page from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Mt228282.aspx#DragAndDrop

Comment: Hey, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278613/does-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-still-support-drag-and-drop-package-inst

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Visual Studio is using a different version of ADB than the emulator is. There can be multiple Android SDKs on the same machine, each with their own version of ADB running.

First, go to the Registry Editor and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools and make sure check the value for "Path." This is the SDK location that the Emulator uses for ADB (and therefore drag-and-drop).

In Visual Studio 2015, Open Tools > Options... and go to "Cross Platform"

If the Android SDK path is different than the one in the registry, update the registry entry to match this path.

If you have Android Studio, you may also want to check the registry entry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Android Studio to ensure that it is using the same version of ADB as well.

Comment: There is no "Android SDK Tools" key under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node".