# Does Visual Studio Emulator for Android still support drag and drop package installation?

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

I installed a package on [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx) by drag-and-drop before.  I got a new update yesterday. The emulator does not seem to support drag-and-drop anymore.  Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This can happen if you are running the emulator with elevated permissions. Try re-running without elevation (not as Administrator).

Comment: Hallelujah!!!  Thank you! Now everything makes sense.  I blame myself for forgetting what happened exactly. I could install by drag&drop initially because I was starting VSEM from the search charm. Later, I got lazy and added a VSEM button to the toolbar of Android Studio, and started using VSEM by clicking that button.  That is when drag&drop stopped working.  It coincided with a new update of VSEM, so I started wondering whether the update disabled the drag&drop. Now the drag & drop works if I start VSEM from the search charm.

Comment: Happened the same to me. I always run VS with elevated permissions so the emulator ends up running with elevated permissions as well. Opening "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" from the start menu solved the problem for me. Thanks

Comment: OMG.  THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the emulator is unable to connect to ADB. See this document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#DragAndDrop for how to make sure ADB can connect to the emulator.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  adb.exe devices does list the emulator.  I can install an app by running it from Android Studio without any problem. It is just the drag&drop that does not work. When I drag a file (apk or zip) to the emulator, nothing happens.  The cursor changes to a circle with a slash when a file is dragged to the emulator.